# Finding the biggest cuboid in a volume, but cheaply

Tags: java, loops, optimization

I'm trying to reduce an amorphous shape into a series of cuboids, in order to then assign those cuboids as distinct rooms with distinct functions. Due to platform necessity, this is being coded in Java.

1. First, the available volume is described as a list of positions 1 metre apart. For reasons of comedic association, this list is referred to as pendingLegos.
2. Then I test each position in the volume for the largest contiguous cuboid that can be generated from it (North, East, and Up).
3. The largest cuboid (or Lego, as the visual display of the rooms resembles building the interior space out of Lego bricks) found is then added to my potential room list, and all of its contained positions are removed from the volume position list. This means that every successive room is identified using a shrinking list of possible positions.
4. Loop until the largest possible room is too small for any meaningful purpose.

To summarise this process:

```
while(pendingLegos isn't empty)
    maxCube = null;
    for-each(position : pendingLegos)
        cube = new Cube(position);
        while(can grow in X direction)
            grow cube in X direction;
        while(can grow in Y direction)
            grow cube in Y direction;
        while(can grow in Z direction)
            grow cube in Z direction;

        if(cube > maxCube || maxCube == null) maxCube = cube;

    if(maxCube > minimum size)
        add maxCube to rooms;
        remove maxCube positions from pendingLegos;
    else
        empty pendingLegos
```

This method works very well at giving me a set of rooms I can use in any given interior space, but it has two flaws. The less significant is that it has no way of understanding open space, which currently I'm experimenting ways to address with the initial volume calculation.

The most significant problem is that, whilst the loop gets easier on the CPU with each new room identified, it always runs very heavy initially. Is there a means of performing this process that is more streamlined and/or efficient?